# 22.04 offline installation

Tags: apt, system-installation, 22.04, offline

For a system without internet access, I've downloaded both ubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso and ubuntu-22.04-live-server-amd64.iso.
I installed from the live-server installation and configured no network access.

I tried to follow
https://techpiezo.com/linux/use-iso-image-as-cd-rom-repository-in-ubuntu/
which mounts the cd iso image and adds the file link to `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

If I delete any external links in the `sources.list`, `sudo apt update` does not give an error, but nothing can be installed from the repository.

It always results in

```
E: Unable to locate package <XXX>
```

No difference if I re-mount the ubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso.

Comment: This method works if you have an iso with apt repository. ubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso and ubuntu-22.04-live-server-amd64.iso cannot be used for this purpose.

Comment: And in any case if you're trying to install something not available in the installation image it couldn't possibly work.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `ubuntu-22.04-live-server-amd64.iso` mounted at `/cdrom` then you can use this configuration for your `sources.list`.

```
deb [check-date=no] file:///cdrom jammy main restricted
```

This is exactly the configuration the live-server installer (*subiquity*) itself [uses during installation](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/blob/b07405a744d47052b4dfc1cf4c32d8dc6559c63c/subiquity/server/apt.py#L224).

You will be limited to packages that are available on the iso.  You can see what's available with the command `apt-get update && apt-cache pkgnames`

I don't know about the Desktop iso.